# How can I add standard errors in regression lines?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

Perhaps this will be quick for some of you but I would like to represent the standard error of the regression using `plot()`.

So, if I have a data like this:

```
x1 <- 1:500
b0 <- 17 
b1 <- 0.5 
sigma <- 7 
er <- rnorm(x1,0,sigma)
y <- b0 + b1*x1 + er 

model1 <- lm(y~x1)
plot(x1,y)
abline(model1,col="red",lwd=5)
```

[image: afadassaf]

How could I represent the standard error, in lines, for that regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you plot the confidence band: `lines(x1[order(x1)], predict(model1, interval = "confidence")[, "lwr"][order(x1)]); 
lines(x1[order(x1)], predict(model1, interval = "confidence")[, "upr"][order(x1)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `ggplot()` instead of `plot()`. You have a slightly more modern layout and much more possibilities.

Add the following code after your example code. For better visibility I have changed the original data a bit (See line: `y <- b0 + b1*x1 + er*5`.)

```
# ------ test case ggplot ----------------
library (ggplot2)
# --- change some data fields ------------
y <- b0 + b1*x1 + er*5

df <- data.frame(y,x1)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x1,y)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method="lm", color="red", fill = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually calculating the regression without the error and from that put the general lines of the `sd()` of all the residual errors:

```
x1 <- 1:500
b0 <- 17 
b1 <- 0.5 
sigma <- 7 
er <- rnorm(x1,0,sigma)
y <- b0 + b1*x1 + er 


GeneralStandardDev<-sd(model1$residuals)
UpperLine<- model1$coefficients[1]+model1$coefficients[2]*x1 + GeneralStandardDev
LowerLine<- model1$coefficients[1]+model1$coefficients[2]*x1 - GeneralStandardDev


model1 <- lm(y~x1)
plot(x1,y)
abline(model1,col="red",lwd=5)
lines(x1, UpperLine, col = "blue")
lines(x1, LowerLine, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but your calculation is not calculating "the standard error of the regression" (whatever the OP means by that).

Comment: What is then for you the standard error of the regression ? Then I might be wrong about the meaning of "the standard error of the regression".

Comment: I don't know what OP means by that. But you are not calculating a standard error. Use `predict(model1, se.fit = TRUE)` if you want to calculate the standard error of predictions.